# The order of static class members

Tags: c++, c++11

Today I've found that the order of static class members actually matters.
Here's is the example:

```
template <typename T>
struct SizeOf
{
    template <typename U>
    static auto Test() { return U{}; }

    static const size_t value = sizeof(Test<T>());
};

std::cout << SizeOf<double>::value << std::endl; // ok!
```

However, this case gives me compiler error:

```
template <typename T>
struct SizeOf
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(Test<T>());

    template <typename U>
    static auto Test() { return U{}; }
};

std::cout << SizeOf<double>::value << std::endl; // error: "Test: undeclared identifier"
```

Does it mean, that static members are treated exactly like global variables/functions, so are not seen by static members that come later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the order of the names becoming known to the compiler.  When you have

```
template <typename T>
struct SizeOf
{
    static const size_t value = sizeof(Test<T>());

    template <typename U>
    static auto Test() { return U{}; }
};
```

The compiler has never seen `Test` in `static const size_t value = sizeof(Test<T>());` so it throws

> Test: undeclared identifier

Because it has no idea what it is.  When you have it the other way around the compiler knows what `Test` is so it compiles just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot reference something which hasn't been declared. When the compiler encounters `Test<T>` how should he meaningful deduce what you actual mean?

Comment: To be fair, you can actually reference something which hasn't been declared yet. One example are the class methods - you can call another method of a class inside an inlined method, although the called method is only declared later inside the class declaration. But it does not work so with type (class) declarations, although nested.

Comment: (another example are the class member attributes - you can also refer to them inside methods earlier in the source code despite the compiler didn't "see" them yet, when they are only declared at the end of the class declaration)